# Insert RSS Feed Content Into Marketo HTML Email Content

Tags: json, email, rss, html-email, marketo

I was wondering if it is possible to Insert content from an RSS feed into the content of an email in Marketo?

We also have an API that returns content in JSON format, is it possible to insert content from that feed into the content of an email in Marketo?

Can’t seem to find much info about it online or on Marketo support forums so hope someone can advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to generate a newsletter type email from your RSS content, you'd probably want to use the Schedule Campaign call to insert your content via a My Token: https://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/schedule-campaign/  It would work similarly to the process described [here](http://developers.marketo.com/blog/sending-transactional-emails-with-the-marketo-rest-api-part-1/), except you need to use a batch campaign instead of a requestable trigger campaign and you would need to have a my token(s) in your email to replace your content with. Your call would ultimately look something like this:

```
{
   "input":
      {
         "runAt": "2014-03-26T18:04:10+0000",
         "tokens" : [
            {
               "name": "{{my.RSSContent}}",
               "value": <RSSContent>
            },
        ]
      }
}
```

There are also some launpoint partners which implement this, like [Digesto](http://launchpoint.marketo.com/perkuto/1248-digesto-rss-to-email-for-marketo/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Marketo or Pardot [FeedOtter](https://www.feedotter.com/) may be of help as well